# While Git rebasing, and fixing the conflict, the file doesn't appear to be modified anymore

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-merge-conflict

I am trying to do a `git rebase` to master. I have `28` rebases. So, on some stages, I get conflicts. I make the adjustments, then I do `git status`, and the modified files appear. However, when I do `git add {filename}`, sometimes the files disappear from the `modified` and the `changes to be committed` list.

Is it because of some `git` bugs or because I have unintentionally made the code to be same as the `master` branch?

Comment: Most likely it is because you made the file identical to the version that is in `HEAD`.

Comment: You don't have "28 rebases", you have 28 *commits* (all in one rebase). That's just a side point, though.

Comment: @torek Thanks for the clarification :) Still learning `git`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is [the disappearing status] ... because I have unintentionally made the code to be same as the `master` branch?

Probably—although "unintentionally" could be wrong; maybe you made it that way on purpose, without realizing that this *was* your purpose.  It's not quite right to say "the same as the `master` branch", though.  As [j6t said in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42233670/while-git-rebasing-and-fixing-the-conflict-the-file-doesnt-appear-to-be-modif#comment71626978_42233670), it means that the file is now identical to the `HEAD` commit.

Before we get to details, let me go back to this:

> However, when I do `git add {filename}`, sometimes the files disappear from the `modified` and the `changes to be committed` list.

Let's take a look at what `git status` actually does.  First, let's define the *work tree*, the *index*, and both a *commit* generally, and specifically the *HEAD* commit.  Then, let's look at what a Git diff is.  Then we can get to `git status` and look at the process of `git rebase`.

For this purpose, remember that a *file tree* (or just *tree*) is a collection of files, starting with a top level directory (or "folder" if you prefer that term), which may contain additional sub-directories ("sub-folders") as well as containing files.  The *tree* is the top level directory with all its contents: all its own files, plus any sub-trees and their files, and any sub-sub-trees and so on.

#### The work tree, the index, commits, and `HEAD`

Your *work tree* is just that: the tree (directory) where you do your work.  It has all your files in the normal formats that your editor and the rest of your computer can work with.  (It can also have files that do not participate in Git: these are called *untracked* files.  If you build source into object code, or turn Python into byte-compiled `*.pyc` files, for instance, those are kept as work-tree-only, i.e., untracked, on purpose.)

The *index*—which is also called the *staging area*, and sometimes the *cache*—is simply where you build the *next* commit.  Using `git add <path>` *copies* the given `<path>` from the work-tree into the index, replacing the version of the file that was there before.  When you eventually run `git commit`, Git turns whatever is in the index—which includes any subdirectories and their files, as well as all the top-level files—into a new commit.<sup>1</sup>

*Commits* are the main reason Git exists at all.  Each commit stores one tree.  That tree is a snapshot of what you had in your index when you made the commit.  Each commit also stores some *metadata*.  I won't define this term fully here, but instead just use the example of the actual metadata for each commit.  These are:

- The tree itself.  (The snapshot is a separate entity from the commit.  We don't really need to care about that here, but it can matter later, and we might as well describe in properly.)
- A list of *parent* commit IDs, usually just one ID.  This is the commit that *was* in place just before you made the new commit.
- An author: a name, an email address, and a time-stamp.  This is the person who wrote the new code, or new text, or whatever it is that is "new" about this commit, as compared to the commit that *was* in place just before now.
- A committer: the same idea as an author, just a second person in case the person who wrote the new commit is not the person who ran `git commit`.  This happens with emailed patches, for instance.
- A log message.  This is free-form text, meant for whoever makes the commit to provide a good description of *why* they made this commit.

Because each commit stores the ID of the commit that came right before it, a series or chain of commits lets us view the history of the development:

```
A <- B <- C   <-- master
```

Here commit `C` is the latest on `master`.  (Its actual ID is some big ugly SHA-1 hash, `badf00daddc0ffee...` or whatever.)  Commit `C` has the hash ID of commit `B`, which lets Git *find* commit `B`, and `B` has the ID of `A`.  The name `master` is how Git finds commit `C`.

There is always a `HEAD` commit.<sup>2</sup>  This is your *current* commit.  Normally, this is also the tip of some branch: for instance, normally you might be `on branch master`, as `git status` would say, and then `HEAD` would resolve to commit `C`.  But you can have `HEAD` point to some other commit, and in this case, `HEAD` is just "the current commit".

Making a *new* commit turns the index into a snapshot (tree) and makes the new commit using that tree.  The parent of the new commit is the old `HEAD`, and then Git updates `HEAD` so that it points to the *new* commit.  If you're on a branch, Git does this updating by making the *branch name* point to the new commit:

```
A <- B <- C <- D   <-- master (HEAD)
```

If you're *not* on a branch, then `HEAD` actually contains a raw commit ID.  In this case, `git commit` writes the new commit ID directly into `HEAD`.  (This is what happens during your conflicted `git rebase`, which is why I mention it.)  But in any case, see how commit `D` here points back to commit `C`: the new snapshot always refers back to the previous one.

Again, the `HEAD` commit is always the *current* commit.  We'll need this in a moment, when we get into the rebase action.

---

<sup>1</sup>This isn't quite precise.  The index is what you get if you *recursively flatten* a tree.  This makes it easy(ish) to turn the index into a tree—so this is what Git does here: it turns the index *into* a tree, using `git write-tree`.  This gets Git one of those big ugly SHA-1 hash IDs.  Git then uses this hash ID for the new commit.  By copying the index to a tree, then putting the tree ID in a commit, Git winds up saving the index's contents as the new commit's snapshot.

<sup>2</sup>There is one exception to this rule.  This exception is required by the fact that an initial, empty repository has *no* commits.  Clearly, if there are *no* commits, it's impossible to resolve `HEAD` to a commit hash ID.  For our purposes, though, we don't need to care about this special case of an "orphan" or "unborn" branch.

---

#### `git diff`, and two vs three trees

While `git diff` has a *lot* of options and usage patterns, the simplest and most straightforward is to compare two trees.  One tree is labeled `a` and the other is `b`.  The diff itself consists of a set of instructions, which mostly amount to things like: "To change `a/README.txt` to `b/README.txt`, remove the 12th line that's there now, and insert this other line for line 12.  Here is some context around line 12 as well."  This means that the file in question is named `README.txt` and is at the top level of the tree—if it were in some sub-tree, the output would say `a/subdir/README.txt` and `b/subdir/README.txt`, for instance.

One of the two trees is often your work-tree.  You can also use the index as if it were a tree.  Or, you can use any commit—such as the HEAD (current) commit—as a tree; Git simply finds the snapshotted tree that goes with that commit.

Rather than getting a set of instructions, "here's how to change README.txt", "here's how to change main.py", and so on, we often just want a list of file names.  We can get this from `git diff` using `--name-only` or `--name-status`.  The `--name-only` flag tells it to print only the name: `README.txt` or `main.py`.  Using `--name-status` adds a *status* as well: `M` for modified, `A` for newly added, and so on.

Note that given any ordinary snapshot commit, with one parent commit, we can `git diff` that commit against its (single) parent.  This will show us what *changed* in that commit.  That's what `git show` and `git log -p` do: they print some information about the commit, then run `git diff` against the commit's parent.

In any case, though, `git diff` only compares *two* trees at a time.<sup>3</sup>  But here you are, just about ready to run `git commit`, and you have, in effect, *three* trees:

1. your HEAD (current) commit;
2. your index; and
3. your work-tree.

It would be nice to be able to compare all three.  Enter `git status`.

---

<sup>3</sup>Actually, `git diff` *can* compare more than two trees, producing what it calls a *combined diff*.  The `git show` command does this for merge commits (`git log -p` normally just skips over them, diff-wise).  But this is tricky, and more importantly, does not do what we want for `git status`.

---

#### `git status`

What `git status` does is to run *two* `git diff`s.  Each one gets a slight variant of `--name-status` applied.

The first diff is `HEAD` vs index.  This diff, between the current commit and your index, are "changes to be committed".  Remember that `git commit` will write the index to the new commit.  If we did that now—if we turned the current index into a new commit—and then viewed that commit as compared to the *current* commit, we'd see just what `git log -p` or `git show` would show.  These would be our committed changes.  So that's what this part of `git status` shows.

It doesn't print the actual diff, just file names and a verbose status (e.g., `modified` instead of just `M`).  If we want the actual diff, we must run `git diff --cached`.  This—which uses the old "cache" name for the index—compares `HEAD` vs the index.

Having shown us that, `git status` now runs a *second* `git diff`.  This compares the index vs the work-tree.  If there are files we have not yet `git add`-ed, this will show us which files those are.  Again, we don't see the actual diff, just the file names and status.  If we want the actual diff, we must run `git diff`, which compares index vs work-tree.  Since these are changes we have not yet `git add`-ed, this second `--name-status` style diff from `git status` shows what we *could* `git add`.  Once we do `git add` them, they will be in the index, so this diff from `git status` will stop mentioning the file.

#### What if we change something, then change it back?

Note that in all this process, we're still getting two separate diffs: `HEAD`-vs-index, and index-vs-work-tree.  What if we go straight to `HEAD`-vs-work-tree?

Well, `git status` won't do that, but we can: we can run `git diff HEAD` (without `--cached` this time).  As always, we can use `--name-status` to get just file name and status, or leave it out to get a full diff.

Now, let's say that `git status` says that `README.txt` has changes to be committed, *and* that `README.txt` has changes not staged for commit.  This means `HEAD`-vs-index is different, and index-vs-work-tree is different.  But what if the first change—`HEAD` vs index—is, say:

```
-the color purple
+the colour purple
```

(i.e., we went to British spelling).  And what if the second change, from index to work-tree, is:

```
-the colour purple
+the color purple
```

(i.e., we changed back to American spelling).  If we compare `HEAD` vs work-tree, using `git diff HEAD`, we won't see any changes at all!

If, at this point, we `git add README.txt`, we'll go from having "changes to be committed" *and* "changes not staged for commit" to having no changes.  This is what you are seeing.

#### Rebase is repeated cherry-pick

The `git rebase` command is very much like repeating a lot of individual `git cherry-pick` commands.  Remember those graphs we drew above, with three or four commits on `master`.  Let's draw a bigger graph, with a side branch:

```
...--D--E--F       <-- master
         \
          G--H--I--J--K   <-- sidebr
```

Note that `master` points to commit `F`, while `sidebr` points to commit `K`.  There are five commits on `sidebr` that are not on `master`.  (Commits `E` and earlier are on *both* `sidebr` *and* `master`.  This is a bit peculiar to Git.)  To *rebase* `sidebr` onto `master`, we need to have Git *copy* each of these five commits.

The Git command that copies *one* commit is `git cherry-pick`.  The *way* it copies the one commit is to turn it into a diff, by comparing it to its parent commit, then applying that diff to the place you would like it copied-to.  We want to copy `G` and have the copy come just after `F`, like this:

```
             G'  <-- HEAD
            /
...--D--E--F       <-- master
         \
          G--H--I--J--K   <-- sidebr
```

The new copy—the new commit—is "like `G` but slightly different", so we call it `G'`.  Once we have `G'`, we next want to copy `H`, and have the new copy come *after* `G'`:

```
             G'-H'  <-- HEAD
            /
...--D--E--F       <-- master
         \
          G--H--I--J--K   <-- sidebr
```

We want to repeat this sequence until we have copied `K` to `K'`:

```
             G'-H'-I'-J'-K'  <-- HEAD
            /
...--D--E--F       <-- master
         \
          G--H--I--J--K   <-- sidebr
```

Once they are all copied, the last thing we want—the last step for `git rebase`—is to *move* the branch label `sidebr` to point to the last commit we copied, abandoning the old chain:

```
             G'-H'-I'-J'-K'  <-- sidebr (HEAD)
            /
...--D--E--F       <-- master
         \
          G--H--I--J--K   [abandoned]
```

Now, during all this cherry-picking, it's possible that something in one of the commits—or even in many of them—is already done in commit `F`.  In that case, since we're applying changes derived from scanning the *old* chain, to a snapshot derived by starting from `F`, we'll hit cases where the cherry-picked commit does not apply properly.

Resolving the conflict may result in removing the change: it's not needed as a *change* because it's already in the new *base*.  In this case, we'll stop having any change from `HEAD`—the last commit we successfully copied—to our index.

If we wind up removing *all* the changes from one of these commits, we'll have what Git likes to call an "empty" commit.  (These aren't actually empty, they are just the *same* as the previous commit.  It's not the *commit* that's empty, it's the `git log -p` *patch* that's empty.)  Git by default won't make empty commits, so for these cases, we have to use `git rebase --skip` instead of `git rebase --continue`.  Git tries to figure out, ahead of time, if there will be such "empty copies", and if so, to skip them in advance.  But sometimes it can't figure that out—we only find out that skipping is right when we get there and resolve a conflict.

I always find it a bit suspicious: did I really resolve this correctly?  The change really *is* in the new base?  It's worth looking over the `git log` results from the new base, to make sure you did resolve the conflict correctly.  But it *can* be correct; it *may* be intentional after all.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed explanation. I Appreciate it :)